# how to implement generic beans

Tags: java, generics, javabeans, semantic-web

for a project in the semantic-web context, I am looking for a elegant way to implement generic beans. The beans should represent the individuals stored in the underlying ontology (rdf/owl), whose structure is modifiable. So, the structure of the beans are known only at runtime. There is no underlying static database structure on which the beans can base upon.

I've tried java reflection, but it is not possible to add methods to a java bean this way. The alternative could be to implement an appropriate databinding mechanism.

Any clues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify this a little bit? If you read ontologies why do you want to add methods dynamicaly? I don't the the reason for that. However if you want to do something liek this, try groovy a language similar to java running on the JVM.

Comment: Thanks for the groovy hint. At the moment I am appointed to Java, but maybe we will consider groovy in the future.

Comment: Well in groovy you have closures. Which can be stored in a hash map and by that you can eay add some glue code to execute them later. So you can add dynamic keys (method names) and code (closures) to your ontology items. (And can interface it from Java)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Empire](https://github.com/mhgrove/Empire) -- it's an implementation of a fair portion of JPA for RDF & SPARQL.  It's not quite what you want, doing something *that* dynamic is likely to have to be custom; as another person said, you're better off w/ something like groovy.  But if you do know a schema ahead of time, it could make your life easier.

It does come w/ some utilities for generating beans, though incomplete, from a SPARQL endpoint.  You could probably use that + reflection, and maybe get the kind of system you're talking about.

Comment: Thank you very much, a JPA-RDF combination is exactly what I am looking for. I will have a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may not add a Java field or method to a class or object at run-time. But you may store a java.util.Map instead of a bean.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Thanks for this hint. At the moment we are using this solution with a java.util.Map and it works for now.